# Joining two tables where table 1 has same primary key with table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am really new in mySql as I am still in Year 1 of my Degree. Really need help on this matter.

I want to build an appointment system where I have Table 1(signup) and Table 2(makeappt). I use Dreamweaver and mysql as my database. As in Table 1, the primary key is username as well as Table 2.

My problem is when I testing log in as 'Mia' for an ekample, Mia cannot view her appointment but the system view another user's appointment.
What should I do? I have tried :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t2.username,
    t2.disease,
    t2.date,
    t2.time,
    t1.username,
FROM 
    signup t1 
JOIN makeappt t2 ON t1.username = t2.username;
```

But it does not work.

Table1 (signup) columns: username,name,address,phone num, etc.
Table2 (makeappt) columns: username. disease, date, time.

What is the SQL stmt that can view appointment from Table2 (makeappt) where the username in username. Table1(signup) = username.Table2(makeappt).

What is not working is that, when I put the code as stated in my question at the recordset in dreamweaver, it does not display the information about the appointment booked by the user itself.For ekample, the user that login is Mia,When she click view appointment as she want to view her appointment's information, she see only other user's appointment's information. I thought that it is error at the sql statement itself.but i dont know how to solve it as I ahve tried JOIN and other sql statemnt

This is the code that's giving me problems:

```
    <?php mysql_select_db($database_sdas, $sdas); 
     $query_viewappt = " 
     SELECT DISTINCT t2.username
                   , t2.disease
                   , t2.date
                   , t2.time
                   , t1.username 
                FROM signup t1 
                JOIN makeappt t2 
                  ON t1.username = t2.username
     "; 

     $viewappt = mysql_query($query_viewappt, $sdas) or die(mysql_error()); 

     $row_viewappt = mysql_fetch_assoc($viewappt); 

     $totalRows_viewappt = mysql_num_rows($viewappt); 

     ?>
```

Comment: 1. Abandon Dreamweaver. Textpad is just fine

Comment: Could you post the code that's giving you problems, and describe in more detail what isn't working?

Comment: <?php
mysql_select_db($database_sdas, $sdas);
$query_viewappt = " SELECT distinct t2.username, t2.disease,t2.date, t2.time, t1.username FROM signup as t1 inner join makeappt as t2     on t1.username = t2.username";
$viewappt = mysql_query($query_viewappt, $sdas) or die(mysql_error());
$row_viewappt = mysql_fetch_assoc($viewappt);
$totalRows_viewappt = mysql_num_rows($viewappt);
?>

Comment: What is not working is that, when I put the code as stated in  my question at the recordset in dreamweaver, it does not display the information about the appointment booked by the user itself.For ekample, the user that login is Mia,When she click view appointment as she want to view her appointment's information, she see only other user's appointment's information. I thought that it is error at the sql statement itself.but i dont know how to solve it as I ahve tried JOIN and other sql statemnt.

Comment: add that info to the question

Comment: Why do you need t1 at all? It sounds like all the data you're selecting and filtering on is in t2

Comment: Your SQL looks fine, so something else is wrong.  Instead of trying to debug three things at once (Dreamweaver, PHP, and MySQL) use some tool that lets you type in SQL and execute it directly against MySQL.  Then, check first to make sure that the rows you believe exist really exist in both tables.  If the data is there, please post the definitions for the two tables.

Comment: Also I doubt you need DISTINCT; it will only be slowing things down

Comment: i dont know what is wrong with my sql statement. I cant figure out why I cant view the appointment's information according to the username in both table signup and table makeappt. In short, I just want to view all in makeappt table that have same username with the signup table. I want to join both table but the related things is that the primary key for signup table is the foreign key of the make appt table

Comment: Dave : I need t1 because, in my system, when I log in as Mia for an ekample, I want to view only Mia's information about her appointment. But now T am facing problem that Mia sees other person's appointment's information, not hers. So thats why I want to join the two tables by relating their primary key which is 'username'

Comment: As @Larry says, try your query in your database directly to see if it does what you intend. Is the PHP code here auto-generated by Dreamweaver? If so, I'd not use it - writing things from scratch (or using a proper framework) is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I fully understand your issue, but if I do, the solution is much simpler than you think.

If your only concern is to retrieve 'Mia''s records, then you shouldn't be joining the tables at all. You can get it by using something like

```
  SELECT  username
      ,disease
      ,date
      ,time from makeappt where username='Mia'
```

There is no reason to use DISTINCT as username is primary key and it will be unique.

But if you need some data from t1 together with t2 then you can

```
    SELECT    t2.username
               , t2.disease
               , t2.date
               , t2.time
               , t1.someField
            FROM signup t1 
            JOIN makeappt t2 
             ON t1.username = t2.username and t2.username='Mia'
```

By the way, you may want to rethink your design as your current design will not allow a second appointment for a user(primary key should be unique).